# facebook c# SDK empty me/feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk, feed

I have implemented `me/feed` facebook graph API using **facebook c# SDK** in my *windows phone 8.1 store app*. Suddenly I am getting **BLANK** feeds `data` array.
Looks like access token I am getting with `read_stream` permission which is used already while login, access_token don't have read_stream or users_post any kind of permission. Why those permissions are not appended to access token suddenly.

Anyone facing this issue?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you know that read_stream will be removed in october 2015, right?

Comment: yes, but it is not working now? what is alternative? user_posts?

Comment: using user_posts also getting empty feeds.

Comment: are you trying with a user without a role in the app? did you debug the access token?

Comment: I debug the access token over there it says permission is not added read_stream or user_posts, but its added and read_stream is already granted by user. What is role?

Comment: are you trying with a user who is admin, developer or tester of the app? make sure you get asked for the permission in the login process.

Comment: I was trying with others account and not able to get feeds. but tried with same user in which fb app is created on developer.facebook then its working. what is issue?

Comment: alright, then it´s very clear what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we found out in the comments that you are trying with a user who does not have a role in the App, and it does work with an App Admin/Developer, there is only one explanation: You need to go through a review process with `user_posts` (and most other permissions). Detailed information is in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Without review, that permission will only work for users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer or Tester). Btw, `read_stream` is deprecated and you would not get it approved anyway. User `user_posts` instead.

Dont´t forget to check out the changelog once in a while: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Ok. Thanks for nice explanation. Will change read_stream to user_posts, any change in "me/feed", will that work as it is if I change only permission.

Comment: no, it´s all in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed

Comment: working with me/feed only, just changed permission to user_posts as read_stream will be removed soon. Thanks.